# Why does Windows Phone (7 or 8) allow click trough divs?

Tags: html, css, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

When having two html elements positioned on top of each other and the element behind is containing an anchor tag, IE on WP7 and 8 "clicks through" the top element and clicks the anchor.

Desktop browsers including IE and other mobile devices like Android browser and Mobile Safari doesn't have this behaviour.

html

```
<div class="back">
    <a href="mypage.html">Min sida</a><br />
    <a href="mypage.html">Min sida</a><br />
    <a href="mypage.html">Min sida</a><br />
    <a href="mypage.html">Min sida</a><br />
    <a href="mypage.html">Min sida</a><br />
</div>
<div class="front">
</div>
```

css

```
.back
    {
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .front{
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 2;
        background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
```

The following jsfiddle displays the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/BSunW/6/

Is this the expected behaviour? Is there some way to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem while customizing Foundation 4 select boxes.
What I did is I have catched all clicks for element below dropdown list (it was a .footer-ul div) like this:

```
 wp8fix: function() {
        $('.dropdown').click(function(){
            $('.foooter-ul').bind('click',function(e){
                e.stopPropagation();
                return false;
            });
        });
 }
```

you have to remember to unbind this after you dont need it anymore

$('.foooter-ul').unbind('click');

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.element_on_the_overlay').click(function(e){
                $('.overlay').preventDefault();
            });

$('.overlay').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
            });
```

Hi, I've found this solution.
Hope you enjoy. :D

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that worked for me in WP8 was this:

```
$("input").prop("disabled", true);
$("option").prop("disabled", true);
$("div").prop("disabled", true);
```